# Amazon SDK region provider chain error

Tags: java, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I'm not familiar with AWS SDK but I'm struggling with it for a while by now.

We have a Spring Boot application which has a `@Configuration` class. This class has the method below:

```
@Bean
public AWSLambda getAwsLambda() { 
    return AWSLambdaClientBuilder.defaultClient();
}
```

This method is throwing the following exception:

```
com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to find a region via the 
region provider chain. Must provide an explicit region in the builder
or setup environment to supply a region.
```

The region is provided in the `application.properties` file.

Does anyone have experienced something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out what was going on and I'm sharing with you, if someone else have this issue.

I needed to install the aws-cli through pip. Then I ran `aws configure` and set the access key, secret access key, region and output!

Answer (score 4):

Try to set the region as an environment varible, like:

```
 set AWS_REGION=eu-central-1
```

Comment: I have tried this (AWS_REGION is in my application.properties file)

Comment: application.properties is used by Spring to initialize its own variables  (as `@Value` etc), but AWS SDK don't use this Spring mechanism. So it must come from the environment as I wrote. Try to set the environment variable before running the local application.

Comment: Alternatively you can use the region value received via Spring and set it programmatically to the client builder via the method `withRegion` https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/client/builder/AwsClientBuilder.html#withRegion-java.lang.String-

Comment: I have set the environment var as you told but haven't work as well. I tried `withRegion` before, with no success.